# Calculate Pandas dataframe column with replace function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I`m working on calculating a field in Pandas dataframe. Learning Python, I'm trying to find the best method. 
Dataframe is quite big, over 55 mln rows. It has a few columns among which `date` and `failure` are in my interest. So the dataframe looks like this:

```
date failure
2018-09-09 0
2016-05-12 1
2013-12-12 1
2018-05-12 1
2018-05-12 1
```

I want to calculate `failure_date` `(if failure = 1 then failure_date = date)`.

Tried smth. like this:

```
import pandas as pd
abc = pd.read_pickle('data_abc.pkl')
abc['failure_date'] = abc['failure'].replace(1, abc['date'])
```

The session is busy for a very long time (1.5h). No result so far. Is it a right approach?
Is the a more effective way of calculating column based on condition on others ?

Comment: What should be the value of `abc['failure_date']` if there is no failure?

Comment: Nothing , I just want to get failure_date. The rest is NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code adds a column "failure_date" and sets it to the failure date for the failures. It does not address "non-failures".

```
abc.loc[abc['failure']==1, 'failure_date'] = abc['date']
```

Comment: What about abc.loc[abc['failure']==1, 'failure_date'] = abc['date'] ?  Your method is faster than df.assign() which would make a copy of the dataframe.

Comment: @DavidGaertner Oops, I meant to do just what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks !!! I modified your way to get exactly what I wanted: `abc.loc[abc['failure']==1, 'failure_date'] = abc['date']`.

Comment: Had to add that it took 2 seconds to calculate this, over 55 mln rows, on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind discarding the rest of the dataframe you could get all the dates where failure is 1 like this

```
abc = abc[abc['failure] == 1]
```